# UIWebView to UIImage doesn't render full page

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, uiimage

UIWebview doesn't render content that is far below the screen, and as a result, the screen capture is missing everything below that point.

I can get a screenshot that is the correct size of webview content, and show more than just what was in the visible viewport.
If I scroll before capturing the screenshot, I get more into the screenshot, but some areas are low-res.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
//Declare WebView
@IBOutlet weak var WVDocView: UIWebView!  

//Button to create screenshot
@IBAction func CaptureButton(sender: AnyObject) {
            self.captureWebview()
        }


func captureWebview(){
        WVDocView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
        WVDocView.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, WVDocView.scrollView.contentSize.width, WVDocView.scrollView.contentSize.height)

        //capture the screenshot
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(WVDocView.scrollView.frame.size)
        WVDocView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //Add screenshot to the view
        self.putImgIntoView(screenshot)
    }

func putImgIntoView(img:UIImage){
        //Create UIImageView from the captured screenshot
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)
        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)

        let imgWrap = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, WVDocView.frame.size.height))

        //put imageView into scrollView
        imgWrap.addSubview(imgView)

        imgWrap.contentSize = imgView.image!.size

        //put scrollView onto the screen
        self.view.addSubview(imgWrap)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imgWrap)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UIWebView` conserves resources by not rendering all of the “unseen” content outside its viewport. Instead of changing the frame of the `UIScrollView`, I would try changing the frame of the `UIWebView` to match the scrollview's `contentSize` and then wait a bit for it to render before taking the screenshot. (If the screenshot should appear instantaneous to the user, the wait may be problematic.)

Comment: I changed the second line of captureWebview() to:

WVDocView.frame = CGRectMa....


I also tried delaying everything in captureWebview() after "//capture the screenshot" by 60 seconds, with dispatch_after(). Same result.

Comment: @jairbow How did you do the delay? You must let the program run while doing the delay, so use, for example, an `NSTimer` to schedule the actual screenshot and exit from the function immediately after doing that and setting the `UIWebView` frame. If that doesn't work either, then could be that the content must be on the actual screen before it gets rendered; you could do that by programmatically scrolling (`contentOffset`) through the entire site (with short `NSTimer` delays in between screenfuls).

Comment: I used dispatch_after() to delay the execution. But in the end I ended up doing what you suggested. I programmatically scrolled through the webview and then took the screenshot again. That did it, although some pages near the top became low-res/blurry.